# MultipartConfig getPart must be called before getParameter

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipartconfig

Similar to [Oracle's `MultipartConfig` example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html), I call `request.getParameter()` prior to calling `request.getPart`.

This works fine except for when the size of the file exceeds the `maxFileSize` specified by `MultipartConfig`.

When this is the case, `request.getParameter` returns null.

Is this the intended result? I have to first check that `getPart()` doesn't throw an `IllegalStateException` and only then retrieve regular (text) parameter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained in this link that this is the expected behavior:

http://www.ryanchapin.com/fv-b-4-666/Invocation-of-request-getParts---in-a-Servlet-3-0-doPost-Method-Will-Not-Throw-IllegalStateException.html